# An Async Task issue - Cross-threaded access to forms

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-ctp

**The Simplified 7 Steps :**

1. [MainForm] User Clicks btnAdd Button
2. AddForm will be shown
3. [AddForm] btnCreate is clicked
4. within the btnCreate_Click we run AddProductProcess with an awaiter
   *** We will close the AddForm as soon as the click
   *** And show the MainForm
5. Inside AddProductProcess we run AddProduct with an awaiter
6. We run our AddProduct which will do the lengthy process for us and fill the Application-Level static collection : ProductCollection
7. [MainForm] When the Process AddProductis done we will show the Added Product Item in our lstProducts ListBox.

---

**5 Pieces of Code :**

```
private void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormAddProduct fap = new FormAddProduct(SelCol);
    fap.ShowDialog();
}

private async void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string stProduct = txtProductName.Text;

    await ProductCollection.AddProductProcess(stProduct);
    this.Close();
    MainForm.Show();
}           

public async Task AddProductProcess(string pName)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddProduct(pName));
    // This would be our heavy process
}   

public void AddProduct(string pName)
{
    ProductItem p =  new ProductItem();
    p.Name = pName ;
    p.Position = Count;
    p.GetInfo(); // and some similar heavy methods are inside this
    //ProductCollection.Add(p);
}

public void Add(Product product)
{
    MainForm.lstProduct.Add(product.Name);
}
```

"MainForm.lstProduct.Add" cause a `invalid cross-thread operation` error

I need to add a Task Completion notification on it so can add the result the proper way to the ListBox
Could you help me implement it ?

I should pass this line of code to the code that will execute right after the task is finished.

ProductCollection.Add(p);

Any Ideas on this piece of code and the subject are appreciated,

Comment: please read the [FAQ entry on what kind of questions should be asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: I saw that, what is wrong with it, Isn't it a specific programming question ? All the Questions and concerns I mentioned could be answered with just 5 lines of code.

Comment: ignoring now the question does not show any research effort (which may harm you in terms of reputation), the post does not propose a specific issue or problem. it is not likely to receive any straight forward answers. another thing - you're stating that "All the Questions and concerns ... could be answered with just 5 lines of code", implying the question aggregates several questions that may be broken down into issue-specific posts. one last thing - note that your post only contains one question mark, where are those several questions?

Comment: I had some projects successfully done with Async and with TPL,

Comment: I showed the way I went through for making the objective happen, After that mentioned that it causes error about Cross-Thread access, If this is the problem I knew the former solution wanted to know is it ok or should adapt it with this new pattern e.g. using TaskCompletionSource, I'm in the middle way of Learning and moving my projects to Async and TPL the same time. If I wanted to break down this question again I should have been posted all the pieces, I'll look at it if possible condemn and refresh the questions part, thanks participating

Comment: The problem is that you have to access UI elements from the UI thread. Why are you even using `StartNew()` here? If some part of `AddProduct()` is slow, which one is it and why is it slow?

Comment: @Svick As I mentioned earlier to Mr Henk I knew the last part isn't correct this way and should adapt it with the pattern. I'm in the middle road with TPL and async, I used StartNew() here cause I wanted to assign new task and possibly threads to this lengthy task. If you help me reform it, it will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: maybe the question was a bit vague and I was a bit confused caused of the hurry I had, anyway I had done some codes like the one Henk gave and wasn't new for me, thanks anyone for the participation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the async/await pattern at some points but not where it matters...

```
public async Task AddProductProcess(string pName)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        AddProduct(pName));
}   

public void AddProduct(string pName)  // not async
{
    ...
    ProductCollection.Add(p);
}


public void Add(Product product)  // not async
{
    MainForm.lstProduct.Add(product.Name);
}
```

That last method just runs on a Task, so it is a 'normal'  cross-threading error. You can resolve it in the normal way, using `MainForm.Invoke(...)` but then you might as well remove all the async and await keywords.

To properly use async/await you would have to change it to something like:

```
public async Task AddProductProcess(string pName)
{
    await AddProduct(pName);
}   

public async void AddProduct(string pName)  
{
    ProductItem p =  new ProductItem();
    p.Name = pName ;
    p.Position = Count;
    await p.GetInfo();    // assuming this is doing the heavy work, make async
    ProductCollection.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: I knew that, I wanted to change my previous code into async-based one, and know that this part should change, for example using a TaskCompletionSource or ContinueWith or what else that could use for doing so, but because I'm still not a professional on this wanted to show the whole idea of what I'm looking for and ask a more professional developer on this part helping me redefine this piece of code, If the 5th part is wrong as it is I will try to change it.

Comment: Thanks Henk but this is not the case, There are several heavy methods Like GetInfo, Should I use of await for all of them, Also SHould move to a method called right after the task is finished , maybe something like TaskCompletionSource, could you help me implement it ?

Comment: Also the way you mentioned will do the activity asynchronous but will not increase the performance of the lengthy task, I tried to use Task's StartNew() with that purpose, maybe I didn't use it right, or have better solutions, Any Idea ?

Comment: The Task should be inside GetInfo(), as far as I can tell.

Comment: You are saying that we assume p.GetInfo() to be the heavy process and I place every other similar tasks inside it, instead I wanted to know and deal with AddProduct that way, "AddProduct" is our heavy process, we level upper than the one you assumed, what is missed for that purpose ?

Comment: +1 for the participation but didn't point to my problem, what changes is needed to prepare "AddProduct" as the lengthy method and be notified on it's completion?

Comment: There are different possible solutions which I found, I told this to remove the UI part and post it to after completion methods part in my posts above, anyway thanks

Comment: Lots of things will work, but async/await aims to eliminate completion methods.

Comment: Thanks Henk for all the Info, don't know why someone closed this

Comment: @Sypress - Yes, the closure seems a little overkill. Normally it takes 5 votes, I guess someone just flagged it for the mods. You can ask again, but start at the problem. This was halfway down a particular solution.

Comment: I used one of the different ways possible as I said, hopefully for further problems I will get your assistant as answers to the upcoming questions.